# jquery selector using (this) for form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload, syntax

Not really sure how to word that one for sorry for the awkward title. I have this script that checks file extensions to make sure they are .mp3s.  I just to overcome which selector to use to grab the name of the file.

Example:

```
<form name="uploadsong1" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return ExtensionsOkay();">
<input name="song1" type="file" accept="*.mp3" />
etc..
```

And ExtensionsOkay first grabs the field value.... which I know is the problem...

```
var fieldvalue = $(this).$('input[type=file]').value;
```

The issue comes from the fact that I have multiple forms with uploads. Form names of uploadsong1, uploadsong2, etc...

So by my reasoning, I need to grab the "this" which is the name of the form, then the input that is a file. (The input names increase by 1, 2, 3 etc like the form names).

I know my syntax has to be wrong for grabbing the fieldvalue... help.. and thank you!??

Comment: why don't you take a look at all jquery functions, it's fun believe me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying you want to call the same `ExtensionsOkay()` function from multiple forms you should bind it with jQuery rather than in an inline `onsubmit="..."` attribute. (Actually you should avoid the inline event attributes in general.)

```
$("form").submit(ExtensionsOkay);
```

*Then*, within the function `this` will refer to the form in question so you use it to get the values of fields within the particular form that was submitted. Following are two different ways to select fields within `this`:

```
function ExensionsOkay(event) {
    var fieldvalue = $(this).find('input[type=file]').val();    
    // or
    var fieldvalue = $('input[type=file]', this).val();
    // and then if you want to prevent the form submitting:
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

When jQuery calls your function it will pass as a parameter the event object associated with the submit event (it doesn't matter what you name the parameter, but most people use `event` or `e` - if you don't need to use the event object you don't have to declare the parameter).

If you don't need to call this function from anywhere other than as a submit handler then you don't need to define it separately and associate it as a handler, just do this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    var fieldvalue = $(this).find('input[type=file]').val();
    // etc
    if (someCondition)
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that with `$("form")` you will be getting all forms on the page. To select just some of them give the relevant ones a class and say `$("form.classNameHere")`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I had to read through this a few times, but I completely understand now.  It actually is fairly simple thanks to your layout! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var fieldvalue = $(this).find('input[type=file]').val();
```

Comment: Hmm I had high hopes for this one! However, it is showing up as fieldvalue "undefined"....

Comment: Updated - there is no `value` in jQuery, just `val()`

Comment: Thanks again Zoltan for the quick reply.  However, it still seems to have a problem.  I am still getting undefined.  Logically though, this all seems correct!  Very odd....

Comment: Ahhhh I think because I am using an "onsubmit" called via regular javascript rather than using the $("form").on("submit", that you are using, maybe it is not able to find the "THIS"....  let me move some code around and see what I can do.... Ill report back in a few